# discrepancy in numbers of kernels in Jupyter notebook and Anaconda-Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am running python with Ananconda, and when I load my jupyter notebook, I see that there are 6 kernels available (see image):

```
Last login: Sun Sep 17 12:42:58 on ttys001
MacBook:~ user1$ jupyter notebook
[I 14:53:55.642 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 6 kernels found
[I 14:53:56.470 NotebookApp] JupyterLab alpha preview extension loaded from /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 14:53:56.471 NotebookApp] Running the core application with no additional extensions or settings
[I 14:53:57.374 NotebookApp] [nb_anacondacloud] enabled
[I 14:53:57.379 NotebookApp] [nb_conda] enabled
[I 14:53:57.451 NotebookApp] ✓ nbpresent HTML export ENABLED
[W 14:53:57.452 NotebookApp] ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named nbbrowserpdf.exporters.pdf
[I 14:53:57.457 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/user
```

[image: Jupyter notebook with 6 kernels, Python and R]

But conda and anaconda-navigator show three environments:

```
conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
P34                      /Users/user/anaconda/envs/P34
R                        /Users/user/anaconda/envs/R
root                  *  /Users/user/anaconda
```

[image: Anaconda Navigator with 3 kernels, Python and R]

Furthermore,

```
conda info --json
```

Returns this:

```
{
  "GID": 20, 
  "UID": 503, 
  "channels": [
    "https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/osx-64", 
    "https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/noarch", 
    "https://conda.anaconda.org/r/osx-64", 
    "https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch", 
    "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64", 
    "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch", 
    "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64", 
    "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch", 
    "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64", 
    "https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch"
  ], 
  "conda_build_version": "2.0.2", 
  "conda_env_version": "4.3.25", 
  "conda_location": "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda", 
  "conda_prefix": "/Users/user/anaconda", 
  "conda_private": false, 
  "conda_version": "4.3.25", 
  "default_prefix": "/Users/user/anaconda", 
  "env_vars": {
    "CIO_TEST": "<not set>", 
    "CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV": "<not set>", 
    "CONDA_ENVS_PATH": "<not set>", 
    "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH": "<not set>", 
    "PATH": "/Users/user/Dropbox (Personal)/firefoxdriver_osx/bin:/Users/user/Dropbox (Personal)/chromedriver_osx/bin:/Users/user/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin", 
    "PYTHONHOME": "<not set>", 
    "PYTHONPATH": "<not set>"
  }, 
  "envs": [
    "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/P34", 
    "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/R"
  ], 
  "envs_dirs": [
    "/Users/user/anaconda/envs", 
    "/Users/user/.conda/envs"
  ], 
  "netrc_file": null, 
  "offline": false, 
  "pkgs_dirs": [
    "/Users/user/anaconda/pkgs", 
    "/Users/user/.conda/pkgs"
  ], 
  "platform": "osx-64", 
  "python_version": "2.7.13.final.0", 
  "rc_path": "/Users/user/.condarc", 
  "requests_version": "2.14.2", 
  "root_prefix": "/Users/user/anaconda", 
  "root_writable": true, 
  "site_dirs": [], 
  "sys.executable": "/Users/user/anaconda/bin/python", 
  "sys.prefix": "/Users/user/anaconda", 
  "sys.version": "2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]", 
  "sys_rc_path": "/Users/user/anaconda/.condarc", 
  "user_agent": "conda/4.3.25 requests/2.14.2 CPython/2.7.13 Darwin/16.7.0 OSX/10.12.6", 
  "user_rc_path": "/Users/user/.condarc"
}
```

How can I reconcile what the jupyter notebook has and what conda reports? How can I delete some of the environments reported by Jupyter notebook? This issue is creating with some libraries that I think are loaded in an environment, but end up in one of the "ghost" environments.

Answer (score 0):

Conda ships with [nb_conda_kernels](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels), which bypass the normal kernel mechanism; thus not all program of your computer can see all the kernels.

`nb_conda_kernels` is meant to automatically expose any conda env as a possible kernel. It does (or at least did) that only for the notebook server, thus you seeing more kernels from within the notebook UI.

This has advantages : no more manual registering of kernels – and disadvantages : many other piece of software can't see al the kernels; notably, Atom, Nteract, Nbconvert, and other lower level tools as well, and the issues you are mentioning.

You can deactivate nb_conda_kernel by looking at your jupyter configuration files and remove the options anaconda has enabled; uninstall nb_conda_kernels. Then install kernelspec [the classic way](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

IPython kernels != conda environments. You might have environments with multiple kernels (as in your case environments 'P34' and 'R' have 2 kernels each - for R and Python), or there might be environments without IPython kernels at all.

If you want to remove a conda environment, you do that with `conda env remove -n ENV_NAME` command.

If you want to detach the kernel from Jupyter without removing the whole environment, you can delete the corresponding kernel spec folder. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55120924/1438906) to your other question for the details on how to find the kernel spec folder.