# locating and removing hidden kernels in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to figure out where are my anaconda kernels in my mac, since applications report different things.

If I run:

> jupyter kernelspec list

I get:

> Available kernels:   python2
> /Users/user/anaconda/share/jupyter/kernels/python2

However, when I open Jupiter notebook, I can see and use:

> [I 07:47:21.394 NotebookApp] [nb_conda_kernels] enabled, 4 kernels
> found

Here are some screenshots:
[image]

How can I remove all of those envs and leave only conda root?
Thanks

Comment: Might be an issue with conda environments? You seem to have an env with R and Python and two others with Python only... and somehow jupyter kernelspec list "sees" only one...

Comment: @byouness, not an issue, but the expected behavior. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are using [nb_conda_kernels](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels) package, which **dynamically** adds ipython kernels from other conda environments to Jupyter. Kernel specs for those kernels are not installed in the environment with Jupyter, that's why you don't see them with `jupyter kernelspec list`.

I can guess you run the command from the base (root) environment, thus the listed kernel should correspond to the `Python [conda root]` and `Python [default]` options in the menu.

Two other kernels are located in the 'anaconda' environment. If you activate it before running `jupyter kernelspec list` you will see the kernels' location:

```
source activate anaconda
jupyter kernelspec list
```

If you don't want to dynamically add kernels from other conda environments to Jupyter, remove the 'nb_conda_kernels' package from the environment where Jupyter is installed.